# Which passwordchar shows a black dot (•) in a winforms textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Short question here:

In **.Net 4.0 Winforms**, how do I use the `PasswordChar` property of a `Textbox` to show a common **black dot** as a **character**? Is there perhaps some font I can use that has this as a character?

If I use '`UseSystemPasswordChar = true`' it shows an asterisk (*).

Comment: you can enter your desired character in property named:PasswordChar enter "." (dot) in PasswordChar property

Comment: Some more Unicode circles to copy & paste: ○ ◌‬ ● ◯ ❍ ✪

Comment: For me, if I use 'UseSystemPasswordChar = true' it shows black dot (●) character. My application is running on Windows 10 targeting .NET v4.6.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can use [this one](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CF/index.htm): `●`

You can type it by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing 25CF.

---

Alternately, you may use [this smaller one](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm): `•`

You can type it by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing 2022.

Comment: Just in case anyone's interested, on a mac it's Alt + 8

Comment: If you're stuggling to type hexadecimal unicode characters with alt key in your application - [Can't type Unicode because of keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/q/864944/374397)

Comment: For a List of Fonts that support - [Unicode Character 'BLACK CIRCLE' (U+25CF) Fonts](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/fontsupport.htm)

Answer (score 70):

Use the Unicode Character 'BLACK CIRCLE' (U+25CF)
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CF/index.htm

To copy and paste: ●

Comment: Cannot cut it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 20):

I was also wondering how to store it cleanly in a variable.
As using

```
char c = '•';
```

is not very good practice (I guess). I found out the following way of storing it in a variable

```
char c = (char)0x2022;// or 0x25cf depending on the one you choose
```

or even cleaner

```
char c = '\u2022';// or "\u25cf"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

same for strings

```
string s = "\u2022";
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Answer (score 10):

One more solution to use this Unicode black circle >>

```
Start >> All Programs >> Accessories >> System Tools >> Character Map
```

Then select `Arial font` and choose the `Black circle` copy it and paste it into `PasswordChar` property of the textbox.

That's it....

Answer (score 6):

Below are some different ways to achieve this. Pick the one suits you

1. In fonts like 'Tahoma' and 'Times new Roman' this common password character '●' which is called 'Black circle' has a unicode value 0x25CF. Set the PasswordChar property with either the value 0x25CF or copy paste the actual character itself.
2. If you want to display the Black Circle by default then enable visual styles which should replace the default password character from '*' to '●' by default irrespective of the font.
3. Another alternative is to use 'Wingdings 2' font on the TextBox and set the password character to 0x97. This should work even if the application is not compatible with unicode. Refer to charMap.exe to get better idea on different fonts and characters supported.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copy/paste a unicode character or setting it in the code-behind you could also change the properties of the `TextBox`. Simply set `UseSystemPasswordChar` to `True` and everything will be done for you by the Framework. Like this:

```
this.txtPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

Comment: This is usually the best solution if you're building a password input field. In my case however, I just need a representation of a password that isn't shown to the user so I needed the character itself to repeat a few times.