# Which passwordchar shows a black dot (•) in a winforms textbox using code?

Tags: c#, winforms, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which passwordchar shows a black dot (•) in a winforms textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051302/which-passwordchar-shows-a-black-dot-in-a-winforms-textbox)
>   [Unicode encoding for string literals in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11)

I want to use code to reveal the password or make it a dot like •

```
textBoxNewPassword.PasswordChar = (char)0149;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: its not a duplicate. I am trying 2 do it in code. The other guy did it using the properties in the Designer

Comment: You can try `textBoxNewPassword.PasswordChar ='\u2022'`.

Comment: @CocoaDev What difference does it make? Just copy/paste the character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://blog.billsdon.com/2011/04/dot-password-character-c/ suggests '\u25CF';

Or try copy pasting this •

Answer (score 7):

(not exactly an answer to your question, but still)

You can also use the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property to select the default password character of the system:

```
textBoxNewPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
```

Often mapped to the dot, and always creating a consistent user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into using the `PasswordBox` control and setting the `PasswordChar` as `*`.

**Example:**

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*'; // Set a text box for password input
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has [a table of similar symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct#Similar_symbols).

In C#, to make a `char` literal corresponding to U+2022 (for example) use `'\u2022'`. (It's also fine to cast an integer literal as you do in your question, `(char)8226`)

---

Late addition. The reason why your original approach was unsuccessful, is that the value `149` you had is not a Unicode code point. Instead it comes from [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), and **Windows-1252 is not a subset of Unicode**. In Unicode, decimal `149` means the [C1 control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) *"Message Waiting"*.

You could translate from Windows-1252 with:

```
textBoxNewPassword.PasswordChar = 
  Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(new byte[] { 149, })[0];
```

but it is easier to use the Unicode value directly of course.

---

In newer versions of .NET, you need to call:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

before you can use something like `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBoxNewPassword.PasswordChar = '\u25CF';
```